# Defining constants in TensorFlow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am using Python 2.7 with the TensorFlow library. In this library, there is a data type called `tf.constant(3)`, which means a constant float of value 3. The value needs to be assigned at initialisation and cannot be changed, similar to a `const` in C++.

In my code however, I do not know the value of this constant at the start. Instead, I need to call a function, which does some processing and then creates the constant. For example, if the constant is called `x`:

```
def initialise_x():
    #
    # Do some stuff
    #
    y = ...
    x = tf.constant(y)
```

The problem with this, is that `x` is now not available outside the scope of the function `initialise_x()`.

So, I want to do something like:

```
x = tf.constant(0)

def initialise_x():
    #
    # Do some stuff
    #
    y = ...
    x = tf.constant(y)
```

But this is not possible, because the constant can only be defined once.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how your program looks like, but how about making a function that returns a constant?

```
def initialize_x():
    # Do something
    y = ...
    return tf.constant(y)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    ...
    x = initialize_x()
    ...
```

Comment: Yes, I thought about that. It makes my code a little messy, but may be the only solution!

Comment: You can move that function into a module, if it contains a lot of logics and looks messy. In that case, `x` is too short to understand, so I recommend you to rename it more understandable one.